# How to get 6V DC motor running using PWM through STM board

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, mosfet, dc-motor, stm32f4

First image is edit of image 2.
Use this circuit to build unidirectional motor control using PWM.

Ignore 3v pin, MOSFET can be any mosfet having small threshold gate-source voltage eg, 30N06, Fairchild TO52-AA.
These MOSFETS are very small, it will be not easy to connect it to bread board. Everything after the first image are questions.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flRd6P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have taken help from previous posts to redraw the circuit, but the 6v motor is not driving at all.
However, instead of connecting PD12 pin, if I connect 5v pin from STM board , motor rotates good without PWM.
MOSFET Gate is connected to PWM signal, Drain is connected to motor and Source to Ground.
Frequency used in STM board for the pin is 10kHZ.

Details of mosfet used is [here](http://www.datasheetspdf.com/PDF/IRFZ44N/509097/1).

Also, there is an onboard LED connected to pd12 pin in stm32f407 board, it blinks as written in the code, this shows that PWM signal is working fine.

What changes should be done so that motor can be controlled unidirectionally using only the software code written for board? what is wrong here.
Is the signal of 10-20mA from microcontroller not enough for MOSFET to amplify it?

Confused.

[image: Circuit to drive motor using PWM from STM board]

Comment: You've not shown how the mosfet is connected. How is the drain and source connected? Most likely you've switched the drain and source pins. Also what's the rationale behind the 220R resistor? Most pull down resistors are 10K.

Comment: I have edited the question adding details about mosfet, I do not know much about resistor value connected  here. I had this resistor, so I connected it to provide pull down effect as stated in other posts. What will be the change if I add 1k resistor?

Comment: That shouldn't cause much difference. Have you tried with a different mosfet? Also try switching it on from the STM device and measure the voltage on PD12. If it's not between 4.5 and 5V then something is loading that pin causing it drop voltage.

Comment: Put a 1 K series resistor between your STM32F407 logic output and the FET gate. This limits the current to/from the gate capacitance during PWM output switching to 5 mA max, otherwise the PWM output is driving into a short-circuit on its rising edge. Change the pull-down to 10 K as suggested, drains leakage current from output before MCU has configured pin to output on power-up.

Comment: Thank you electrophile and TonyM. Now, I don't have required resistors, i will change the resistors and tell about it.

Comment: @electrophile should the mosfet be changed, or other mosfet of same series be used?, in case even after adding the resistors the circuit don't work.

Comment: It may not be your immediate problem but the presumably 3.3v output from the STM32 may be marginal for the gate threshold of the IRZ44.  If that is an ordinary small 9v battery you must have a low current motor, so you'd could use a small "logic level" FET with a lower gate threshold.  The DMN2041L for example is often used in small quadcopters, and can be driven directly from an MCU pin without a series resistor.  You can carve a bit of copper clad to breakout the pins, get a SOT-23 breakout, or carefully solder wires directly to it and glue the assembly to a scrap of something for stability.

Comment: Also make sure the LED you apparently have connected in parallel has a series resistor - otherwise the LED could be clamping the output at its forward voltage, which may be too low to activate the FET.  Or if you LED is between the output and the positive supply, realize that the LED would be on when the motor is off.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Is it a concern about the gate threshold voltage VGS(Gate to source voltage)? I also thought of it because if you see the second page of link for irfz44n VGS is 2 to 4v. I checked for DMN2041L its very low 0.5 to 1.5v. But, the current from pd12 pin of stm is 10-20mA(seen somewhere in internet) . Is it good to go?? I do not have kit to measure the voltage levels.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Regarding LED, the LED is inbuilt in board, connected to PD12 of board, I haven't connected it by myself. Is the led connected in stm board, a hindrance to provide adequate voltage level out of the board?

Comment: A MOSFET requires a voltage to be achieved, depending on conditions and process variation that could be anywhere from 2 to 4v for the part you chose.  Available current is basically irrelevant - it will only be drawn very briefly to charge the gate capacitance, after that there will for all practical purposes be no current flow.  But if the gate does not reach the necessary voltage because the drive voltage is not high enough, then the FET will not turn on, completely or possibly event at all.

Comment: Hello, schematic is redrawn to show added resistors and 3v voltage for mosfet, is it right way to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56083/discussion-between-abinjacob-and-chris-stratton).

Answer (score 1):

From [IRFZ44](https://www.mouser.ca/Semiconductors/Discrete-Semiconductors/Transistors/MOSFET/_/N-ax1sf?P=1z0z63xZ1z0y3zrZ1ytiyvgZ1yw8qn6Z1yw8om3Z1yw8o1nZ1yw8oxgZ1yw8lpvZ1yw8pzlZ1yw8n3hZ1yw8py4&Rl=ax1sfZgjdhozZ1yw76gfZ1yvy0nySGT&Ns=Pricing%7C0) datasheet it appears +3v3 won't be enough to drive current for a DC motor. From the typical output plot:

[image: IRFZ44-Output]

Vgs of +4v5 would drive 8A, considering Vds=9V. Extrapolating the curves you could guess that, with +3v3, Id would be close to 1A or lower. It appears that +3v3 is too low for Vgs threshold. Does connecting gate directly to +3v3 properly drive the motor? Can you measure the motor current in this condition?

You could try using a simple NPN as a buffer for gate voltage, like here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmogOl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just be aware that in this case the current will flow though the motor when PWM voltage is below ~500mV.

Or you could try these MOSFETs: [Mouser - N-MOSFET](https://www.mouser.ca/Semiconductors/Discrete-Semiconductors/Transistors/MOSFET/_/N-ax1sf?P=1z0z63xZ1z0y3zrZ1ytiyvgZ1yw8qn6Z1yw8om3Z1yw8o1nZ1yw8oxgZ1yw8lpvZ1yw8pzlZ1yw8n3hZ1yw8py4&Rl=ax1sfZgjdhozZ1yw76gfZ1yvy0nySGT&Ns=Pricing%7C0)